# Are Django DB connections isolated between process?

Tags: django

If I close db connection in one process, will it affect other processes?

Example:

I'm running the same application with:

- gunicorn
- celery
- Management command: python /../../manage.py somecommand

If I do something like this in `somecommand`:

```
from django.db import connection
connection.close_all()
```

In that case will the connection to the database be closed in gunicorn and celery instances?

PS. `CONN_MAX_AGE` is set to 3600.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the whole point of processes is that there's no way an action on an object in memory in one process can affect any of the others.